# how do i add placeholder in textbox with css

Tags: placeholder

I do have old struts project, I want to put placeholder with the help of existing css class , because I have to do this change 100`s of number of jsp`s. I want to do it in css once for all.

```
.boxLookupMan
{
  border:1px solid #999;
  background-color:#ffffc7;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  FONT-SIZE: 11.5px;
  color:    black;
  text-indent: 2px;
  background-image: url(/KCBWeb/images/lookupblueman.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  content: "Enter your number";
}
```

I have added content attribute in boxLookupMan class after which I my textbox should show "Enter your number" text as placeholder.which is not working. Please , suggest other ways of doing it or improvement in current css.

Answer (score 0):

The `content` property applies to `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements.

Add ::after or ::before to your style something like:

```
.boxLookupMan::after {
  content: "Enter your number";
  /* ... The rest ... */
}
```

Remeber `pseudo-elements` can't be used with with all `HTML` elements, you CAN'T use it with `<img>`, `<input>` or `<br>` for example, since they can't contain other elements.

[**::after DOCS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

[**content DOCS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)